# Distinguishing generics in Fortran by other than type/kind/rank

Tags: pointers, fortran, standards, explicit-interface, allocatable-array

I make **huge** use of non-`1` indexed `ALLOCATABLE` arrays, whose actual lower (and thus upper) bounds I want to be known for the procedures they're given to as `IN`/`INOUT` args (so I declare these dummy arguments as deferred-shape arrays to make them be passed along with their bounds; see `f_deferred_all` in the example code).

But.

Sometimes these procedures (after the data-declaration part) can deal with actual arguments being subarrays, so when this is needed, I usually end up making a copy of the procedure, changing its argument declaration along with its name (*cf.* procedure `f_assumed`). And it would be nice to put both procedures under the same name by means of an `INTERFACE`. But the [standard](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf) says I cant, since

> Interfaces of specific procedures or bindings are distinguished by
>   fixed properties of their arguments, specifically type, kind type
>   parameters, rank, and whether the dummy argument has the POINTER or
>   ALLOCATABLE attribute.

In the following example program, I overcame this "limitation" by using pointer actual and dummy arguments (see `f_deferred_ptr`).

1. Is this "solution" somehow deprecated, discouraged, dangerous or anything else? I ask this because I really haven't been using `POINTER`s so much.

In addition, I defined a `pntr` function that returns a `POINTER` to its sole (non-`ALLOCATABLE` array or section of an array) `IN`put argument, so that I can use it "in-line" without defining a `POINTER` in the main program and I don't have to put the `TARGET` attribute on the actual arguments.

2. Do I have, by using `pntr`, a temporary array be created? I think yes, but I'm not sure whether defining the `POINTER` and associate it in the main program would make a difference in this respect or not.
3. Would it be possible/is it planned/would it make sense for the standard to be changed to allow such distinction between generics? Where is it to post such suggestions, provided they make sense?

Here the example follows.

```
module mymod

    implicit none

    interface f
        module procedure f_deferred_all, f_deferred_ptr!, f_assumed
    end interface f

    contains

    integer function f_assumed(x) result(y)
        integer, dimension(:), intent(in)  :: x
        y = lbound(x,1)
    end function f_assumed

    integer function f_deferred_ptr(x) result(y)
        integer, pointer,     dimension(:), intent(in) :: x
        y = lbound(x,1)
    end function f_deferred_ptr

    integer function f_deferred_all(x) result(y)
        integer, allocatable, dimension(:), intent(in) :: x
        y = lbound(x,1)
    end function f_deferred_all

    function pntr(v) result(vp)
        integer, dimension(:), target, intent(in)  :: v
        integer, dimension(:), pointer             :: vp
        vp => v
    end function pntr

end module mymod

program prog

    use mymod

    implicit none

    integer :: i
    integer, dimension(-5:5)           :: v1
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: v2

    v1 = [(i, i = 1, 11)]
    allocate(v2, source = v1)

    print *, 'f_assumed(v1)', f_assumed(v1)
    print *, 'f(pntr(v1))', f(pntr(v1(:))) ! is a temporary created?
    print *, 'f(v2)', f(v2)

end program prog
```

Comment: A note: a module should be placed *before* the main program. I am quite surprised it compiles for you.

Comment: Oh, thank you! Fortunately I was using two separate files for the program and the module.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but note that `v1` still needs the target attribute: the function result of `pntr` is pointer associated with the dummy argument `v`so `v1` not having the target attribute means that the function result becomes of undefined association status as soon as the function completes.

Comment: (I hope my question does make sense, at least.) Are you saying that `f` in `f(pntr(v1(:)))` returns the correct value only by chance, depending on the compiler and other stuff?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: So far I am unable to understand what it is you'd like to do. What do you mean by "subarrays"?  Please add a short code example that illustrates what you'd like to do, even if it doesn't work now. Do keep in mind that assumed-shape dummy arguments can take all kinds of arrays, including those with non-unit stride or even vector subscripts.

Comment: @SteveLionel, basically I'd like to uncomment the trailing part of the `module procedure` line, i.e. to be able to call `f(v2)` as well as `f(v1)`, `f(v2(3:))`, ...

Comment: I think you have unnecessarily complicated this. All you need is the f_assumed function and therefore don't need a generic at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example code is non-conforming because the specific names `F_DEFERRED_PTR` and `F_DEFERRED_ALL` are ambiguous. [Technical Corrigendum f08/0001](http://isotc.iso.org/livelink/livelink?func=ll&objId=18597225&objAction=Open) changes the wording in "12.4.3.4.5 Restrictions on generic declarations", adding "**and not the INTENT(IN) attribute**", to

```
Two dummy arguments are distinguishable if
 • one is a procedure and the other is a data object,
 • they are both data objects or known to be functions, and neither is TKR compatible with the other,
 • one has the ALLOCATABLE attribute and the other has the POINTER attribute and not the INTENT(IN) attribute, or
 • one is a function with nonzero rank and the other is not known to be a function.
```

This is prompted by the fact that the actual argument for a POINTER, INTENT(IN) dummy can be a pointer or a valid target for the dummy pointer in a pointer assignment statement (12.5.2.7 Pointer dummy variables [J3/10-007r1](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007r1.pdf)). Links to the [discussion](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-145.txt) and [resolution](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-145r1.txt) of the issue.

Comment: Nice answer. Do you know the reason for the corrigendum? Or even the link for the interp?

Comment: The interp is [here](http://isotc.iso.org/livelink/livelink?func=ll&objId=18570899&objAction=Open)

Comment: Thank you for the links. I actually agree with @francescalus that it would be nice to extend the answer to explicitly describe that a `target` variable can be passed to `pointer, intent(in)` and that's why `pointer, intent(in)` must be avoided in generic disambiguation. I didn't see it immediately, although I perhaps should have.